# Strange encoding in SQLite database: How to retrieve string values with JDBC?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, encoding, character-encoding

I have

```
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:cities.db");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from cities;");+

    while (rs.next()) {
        byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes("country");
        String country = new String(bytes, "utf-8");
        System.out.println(country);
    }

    rs.close();
    conn.close();
```

My output shows � for characters like ä,ö,ü.

If I run `sqlite3` from the command line and query the table from there, the characters are fine...

"pragma encoding;" shows utf-8...

If I debug, the bytes array has "-127" at the place of "ü"...

how to fix that?
what could cause that problem?

link to example SQLite file (only one row):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nvl737b6picbie/cities.db?dl=0

Comment: Don't use getBytes() for Strings - try using getString() instead.

Comment: Also note that System.out.println() might add just another layer of encoding-dependency to your problem. Is your console window / the font you use equipped to show UTF-8 ?

Comment: Don't play around with *any* encoding setting. Please note that the Windows command line does not support UTF-8.

Comment: it is also not working the getString, and i am using IntelliJ, and i also checked the value with the Debugger. I added the encoder settings because it is not working, if i get it work without, i wont use them....

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample copy of "cities.db" that can be used to recreate the issue?

Comment: i added a link to the post...

Comment: Thanks for the link. Am I right in assuming that the "Country" value should be 'Türkiye'?

Comment: yes, thats right. if i call "select * from cities" (outside java, with sqlite3 <file>) it is also showing that...

Comment: Not me. When I do the same thing from sqlite3 I get 'T?rkiye'. Are you running Windows? If so, what is your Windows locale? (Mine is "English (United States)".)

Comment: mine is german... but okay, seems like there is nothing wrong with my code. i have the sql file, i will let java execute it line by line, so i have a correct database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that the SQLite database contained characters that were encoded with the old IBM OEM character set ([code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)), so the 'ü' character was encoded as 0x81. That is an unused character in Unicode and all(?) of the ISO-* and Windows-* character sets.

[image]

I was able to extract the "Country" value correctly using

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/__tmp/cities.db";
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL)) {
        String sql = "SELECT Country FROM CITIES";
        try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String s = new String(rs.getBytes(1), "cp437");
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try with

```
Class.forName(org.sqlite.JDBC.class.getCanonicalName());
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:";
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.setEncoding(SQLiteConfig.Encoding.UTF8);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, config.toProperties());
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from cities;");+

while (rs.next()) {
    String country = rs.getString("country");
    System.out.println(country);
}
```

Comment: i  also alreay tried that, but the output is worse.

Comment: Could you try putting a break point on the line `System.out.println(country);`, run in debug mode and see the value that has been retrieved from the DB?

Comment: I have installed SQLite Browser on my computer and opened the cities.db from dropBox and the value for the country is 'T�rkiye'

Comment: When i run the insert statement `insert into cities (country, state, city) values ('Турска', 'Адана', 'Адана')` in SQLite Browser and select all cities, the Cyrillic value is printed correctly both in SQLite Browser and Java program from my answer.

Comment: To conclude: your cities.db does not have correct content.

Comment: i just created a small new database, and it is not working. try to add a "ü" into the database...

Comment: weird, if i add the "ü" the executeQuery, it works, if i insert it from command line via sqlite3 binary it doesnt...